# SQL Basic Join fault

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two SQL queries that work fine by themselves but not when I try to combine them, very likely a basic misunderstanding on my side. These are the queries; the third is my attempt to combine them. What am I missing? I get to high amounts like: Q1/db1: 185 Q2/db2: 180 (This is OK, I'm writing the query to find discrepancies.) Q3: db1: 925 db2: 2340 which gives a 5 and 13 multiplier respectively.

Note: Item_ID and ArticleNo are text fields in different versions of my language, hence the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT. They do contain the same info.
Running on SQL Server 2008 R2

I have done some anonymization to the dbo names.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, ROUND(SUM(i.Quantity), 0)) AS CUB,
       i.Item_ID
FROM [dbo].[ITEM_CONFIGS] AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LOCATIONS_CONFIGS] AS l ON l.Config_ID = i.Config_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITEMS] AS ii ON i.Item_ID = ii.Item_ID
WHERE i.Quantity > -1
GROUP BY i.Item_ID
ORDER BY i.Item_ID ASC

SELECT SUM(s.UnitInStock) AS UnitInStock,
       s.ArticleNo
FROM [dbo].TotalsView AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Article AS a ON s.ArticleNo = a.ArticleNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Supplier AS r ON a.MainSupplierNo = r.SupplierNo
WHERE s.ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
    AND s.UnitInStock IS NOT NULL
    AND a.InActiveYesNo = 0
GROUP BY s.ArticleNo
ORDER BY s.ArticleNo ASC

SELECT CONVERT(INT, ROUND(SUM(i.Quantity), 0)) AS CUB,
       SUM(s.UnitInStock) AS UnitInStock,
       s.ArticleNo
FROM [dbo].[ITEM_CONFIGS] AS i
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LOCATIONS_CONFIGS] AS l ON l.Config_ID = i.Config_ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ITEMS] AS ii ON i.Item_ID = ii.Item_ID
INNER [dbo].StockSurveyTotalsView AS s ON ii.Item_ID COLLATE database_default =
    s.ArticleNo COLLATE database_default
INNER JOIN [dbo].Article AS a ON s.ArticleNo = a.ArticleNo
WHERE s.ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
    AND s.UnitInStock IS NOT NULL
    AND a.InActiveYesNo = 0
    AND ii.Item_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY s.ArticleNo
ORDER BY s.ArticleNo ASC
```

Comment: Sample data of all tables and expected result will help us to understand better

Comment: Here `INNER  [dbo].StockSurveyTotalsView as s....` `JOIN` keyword is missing

Comment: When you are getting high results after a new `JOIN` it suggests that one (or more) of your tables has caused a `1:many` relationship. A quick way to discover which table is causing your results to balloon is to remove the `GROUP BY` and do a `SELECT *` while keeping your `FROM` the same. You can analyze individual records to find records where you measures are duplicating and then see which table is bringing in multiple results. To help, as @motoGP suggested, you should post some sample data and expected results.

Comment: You deleted the `LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Supplier AS r ON a.MainSupplierNo = r.SupplierNo` line that is in your second query, but not the third.  I realized you deleted it because `r` was never used in second query.  When you anonymized these queries, did you change them a little bit or it really just an unused line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the same first 2 query as CTE and join them to get the result.

```
;WITH CUB AS (
SELECT CONVERT(INT, ROUND(SUM(i.Quantity), 0)) AS CUB,
       i.Item_ID
FROM [dbo].[ITEM_CONFIGS] AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LOCATIONS_CONFIGS] AS l ON l.Config_ID = i.Config_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITEMS] AS ii ON i.Item_ID = ii.Item_ID
WHERE i.Quantity > -1
GROUP BY i.Item_ID
),
UnitInStock AS (
SELECT SUM(s.UnitInStock) AS UnitInStock,
       s.ArticleNo
FROM [dbo].TotalsView AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Article AS a ON s.ArticleNo = a.ArticleNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Supplier AS r ON a.MainSupplierNo = r.SupplierNo
WHERE s.ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
    AND s.UnitInStock IS NOT NULL
    AND a.InActiveYesNo = 0
GROUP BY s.ArticleNo
)
SELECT c.CUB, uis.UnitInStock, uis.ArticleNo FROM CUB AS c
INNER JOIN UnitInStock AS uis ON c.Item_Id COLLATE database_default = uis.ArticleNo COLLATE database_default 
ORDER BY uis.ArticleNo;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs. I have used Zhang's answer and managed to get it to work with proper dbo-names. Further, I have decided to implement the WITH's as views and use those for the SELECT pertion in Zhang's answer.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs. I have used @Zhang Peng 's answer and managed to get it to work with proper dbo-names. Further, I have decided to implement the WITH's as views and use those for the SELECT portion in Zhang's answer. Responses to some comments: MotoGP I'll remember in the future to provide more info and to proofread the question as someone other than myself. JNevill Thanks for the debug tip. Zach Mierzejewski The missing join is a typo caused by the anon C^-X. Item_ID is not in the SELECT in Q3, so I think I got that right.

Answer (score 0):

In your third query, you forgot to implement the `GROUP BY i.Item_ID` line from your first query.  I would use Zhang Peng's CTEs because they're easier to read/understand, but that is the reason **why** his should work and yours may not.